# select distinct using php gives wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

**mysql**

```
select distinct(cat) from code order by cat asc;
```

result - 1 row selected
that's true - because entire `cat` column has the same value.

**php**

```
$st = $db->query("select distinct(cat) from code order by cat asc");
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetch();
echo count($arr); // 2
```

Why I'm getting two rows selected using php?

Comment: I think, fetch() returns associated  and indexed results together

Comment: You can most likely remove the `$st->execute()` part as well. The `$st` variable should already contain the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$st->fetch()` just returns a single row, not all the rows. `count($arr)` is the number of elements in this array. The default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, so the array contains two elements for each column you selected.

```
["cat" => "Category Name", 0 => "Category Name"]
```

To get all the rows, use `$st->fetchAll()`:

```
$rows = $st->fetchAll();
echo count($rows);
```

BTW, `DISTINCT` is not a function, and it doesn't just apply to a single column, so you shouldn't put parentheses after it. It's a keyword that applies to the entire SELECT list. There's no difference when you're only selecting one column, but it would be misleading to write something like `SELECT DISTINCT(col1), col2 ...`.

Comment: finally this confused things - clarified. Thanks a lot